# fvisibility=hidden doesn't work when I add a single __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang, compiler-flags

I'm compiling with Android NDK, and confirmed that setting -fvisibility=hidden (using set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)) reduces size of the binary drastically. But when I add even a single **attribute** ((visibility ("default"))) it goes back up in size and bloaty shows my symbols that were clearly supposed to be hidden.

This is how I set that attribute

```
__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
bool MethodName(const std::string& parameter) noexcept;
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the same root cause as https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/829? Can try building with `-mno-global-merge` to see.

Comment: @DanAlbert: I get a 

clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-global-merge' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
I'm passing it via cmake using 
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " -mno-global-merge")

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also I seem to have the same issue for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute looks ill-formed (I think?).

Quoting your snippet:

```cpp
__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
```

should be

```cpp
__attribute__((visibility ("default")))
```

(referencing [this GCC wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)).